# shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation to current UIView of UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have UIViewController, with 2 UIViews. First UIView is main view. At some point of button action i add subview of second UIView to first UIVIew.

So i want to that if there is just first UIView than it could rotate but if i add subview of other UIView it don't let rotate. So i have to recognize if main view have subview of second view and don't let rotate. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{

     if (_secondView) {
     return NO;
     }
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can return true or false by setting tag of the view and for value of tag you can define macros. Or you can use `button.selected` feature which comes with in the button. This way you can save extra variable to use.

Comment: Thank you all for answers.

I also want to ask one more:

If i have outlet like this:

    @property(nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIView *sView;

and at some point i put it on other UIView to subview. Than i remove it from supreview and i want to add again but i can't. Is this it because when i remove than it autorelease ?

Comment: No, not unless you are setting it to nil. I would recommend you accept an answer then post this as a separate question though.

Comment: No it will not get auto released, Oh check whether you are adding the subview in main thread or not. Please note all UI change call must happen in main thread,

Cheers,
Shravan

Answer (score 0):

Just set a instance boolean variable when the 2nd view is added to true and false when the 2nd view is removed and that should work. Otherwise, please let us know why it is not working.

Comment: Also you need to have your shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: in your VC, not the view.

Answer (score 0):

check if [secondView superView] == nil.  if it's not nil, it means secondView is already part of a view tree (in our case, subview of firstView)